# How to use concatenated minified file in Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, minify

I'm brand new to Gulp and I was able to create a `site.min.js` file, which as I understand is the minified versions of my JavaScript files.

How do I take advantage of that?

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but should my `index.html` also be getting modified to only load the new `min.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you minify a file, the result is a completely different file. You need to link it in your page in order to use it.

```html
<script src="site.min.js"></script>
```

The production version of your `index.html` file should only link to the minified version and any non-minified version should be removed.

There are gulp plugins which help with this.

- [gulp-useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref) is popular
- [gulp-html-replace](https://github.com/VFK/gulp-html-replace) is quite flexible
- [gulp-usemin](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin)
- [gulp-htmlbuild](https://github.com/Janpot/gulp-htmlbuild)

They all offer a similar feature where you can specify blocks within HTML comments that will be replaced by the minified version.

```html
<!-- build:js -->
<script src="website-module.js"></script>
<script src="core.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

With the right options within your gulp task, it would become:

```html
<script src="site.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Got it, I'm a bit surprised that there's dozens of minification and concat examples readily available, but without actually being able to link to the resulting file, all useless, kind of felt like I was missing something.  Thanks for your help!